# Finding password for MySQL 8.0 server after fresh installation

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to set up MySQL to run locally on my Windows machine. I've downloaded the web community installer and selected the developer option.

When installing "samples and examples" I am prompted for a username and password for the server. Next to the username field I see a message saying `"Credentials can be found in server configuration file"`.

Scouring the internet, I have found suggestions to look for my.ini or my.conf files. After searching my entire system, I cannot find either of these files.

How can I retrieve my password?

I've also tried using "root" as the default password. This is my first time dealing with servers and MySQL so pardon if this question has an obvious solution.

Comment: Have you tried username : root password : <leave the field blank> ? If it is not working, reset the password. You can follow: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

Comment: Unfortunately the installer requires a password. I would try the suggestion above, but as I said, I can't find my.ini anywhere -- I've tried looking manually and searching my entire system.

Comment: In that case, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157638/3214266 to see if you have any luck in locating the my.ini file.